# Configuration error. Class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

tengo el siguiente problema espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy trabajando con WildFly de Red Hat, aunque ya lo he probado en otros servidores como Apache y Galssfish. ya agregue ciertos jar`s a los servidores y nada, cree datasorces y tampoco. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

> Context Path:
>   /agendaweb
>
> Servlet Path:
>   /webresources
>
> Path Info:
>   /contacto
>
> Query String:
>   null
>
> Stack Trace
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception Description: Configuration error. Class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found.
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)

Mi archivo POM.XML

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Mi clase ApplicationConfig

> @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
>   public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
>
> @Override
>      public Set> getClasses() {
>           Set> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
>          addRestResourceClasses(resources);
>          return resources;
>      }
>      private void addRestResourceClasses(Set> resources) {
>
> > resources.add(com.mycompany.agendaweb.services.ContactoFacadeREST.class);
> >        }
>
> }

Si necesitan algo mas de información se las brindo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que indicas:

> Exception Description: Configuration error. Class
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found.

puede surgir porque en tu carpeta `WEB-INF/lib` no se encuentra esa librería, prueba con eso y nos comentas

Saludos

Comment: Es correcto tenia un problema con el jar conector de MySQL!!! Gracias!